# How to align an element when it locates below some float elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a DOM structure like below:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="my-wrapper clearfix">
            <div class="float-right">
                float1
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                float2
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                floatN
            </div>
            <div class="my-footer">
                This is footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And some SCSS:

```
.my-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    border: blue solid 1px;

    .float-right {
        float: right;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: grey solid 1px;
    }

    .my-footer {
        clear: both;
        //float: right; 
        border: yellow solid 1px;
    }
}
```

How to align the left side of ".my-footer" and the last ".float-right" vertically?

**[Explanations]:**

1. There are several ".float-right" elements, the count is unknown, and the width of each of them is not fixed, but we can ensure they all in one line, that is to say, there are enough space in ".my-wrapper" to keep them in one line.
2. I expect the result is the ".my-footer" will be displayed in a new line, but its left-side border will align the left side of the last floating ".float-right" element.
3. I'm using bootstrap CSS framework.

[Updated]
 4. I need to support IE9,so flex is not support.
 5. The height of each ".float-right" is unknown either.
 6. I don't want the footer overlap with float boxes.

See the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o4vkojku/) in jsfiddle.

Comment: You expected them to overlap?

Comment: So you want the width of the footer to match the total width of the floating elements, as well as appear below the floating elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `display` for `.my-wrapper` to `inline-block`. This will get rid of its ability to stretch the entire width of its container. Then `float` it to the right:

```
.my-wrapper {
   border: blue solid 1px;
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;

  .float-right {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: grey solid 1px;
  }

  .my-footer {
    clear: both;
    //float: right; 
    border: yellow solid 1px;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nr7ktras/

Comment: @j-titus So simple, thanks! Why didn't i think of it? :)